# Getting an access token for an installed application

Tags: oauth, installed-applications, developer-console

I'm following the "Using OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications" instructions, and have managed to get as far as obtaining the authorization code.  However I'm having trouble working out the next step of getting the actual access token.

One of the request fields is the "redirect_uri" which is supposed to be "The redirect URI you obtained from the Developers Console."  However, I can see nothing in the Developers Console (specific project or not) which offers this information.

Can someone help me out with what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What service are you talking about? oauth is used by many sites on Internet. Best to provide the link to the instruction.

Comment: Argh.  Sorry about that.  It is for the Google Cloud Platform.  The actual page is here: [Google Installed App OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp).